# Merging 2 ubuntu repositories into a single offline repository

Tags: ubuntu, apt, repository

I am currently running apt-mirror to have a local, offline copy of the entire ubuntu repository (both 32&64), from ubuntu 9.04 to 13.10.
Old releases are being apt-mirrored from old-relases.ubuntu.com and the regular ones from one of the mirrors.

The problem is that that the more time passes - the more duplicates I have. There are many similarities between versions so many files are shared between the same version ON THE SAME REPO, the moment I am starting to split archive.ubuntu.com and old-releases.ubuntu.com I get a lot of duplicate files.
I was wondering if there is a simple solution to merge the 2 similar repos from different sites, or if there is a single place that holds everything in a single repo for me to mirror or if there is a simple de-duplication method I can use to save disk space...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We use [apt-cacher-ng](http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/) as an apt caching proxy. It allows remapping of multiple repo's into a single storage. For example, by default it uses this to consolidate the various Ubuntu mirrors that people can use into a single cached repo.

I have not tried your exact use case, so I'm not sure apt-cacher-ng can accomodate you. I'm not sure if the original repo's have to be exact mirrors or if they can be arbitrary repos as long as they don't conflict. Perhaps you can find more info in the Readme.